# Remove dot following specific text

Tags: python, regex, text, text-processing

I'm trying to use remove dot (.) from specific following words like com and org for text cleaning using Python e.g.

> Input: cnnindonesia.com liputan.org

> Output: cnnindonesiacom liputanorg

Anybody has an idea using regex or iterations? Thank you.

Comment: You should include other cases like `foo.comcast.net` in your sample input/output as it's always easy to match the string you want but much harder to not match similar strings you don't want so only including the simple, sunny-day cases in your sample input/output is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replace()` and a list comprehension; regular expressions aren't necessary here:

```py
data = ["cnnindonesia.com", "liputan.org"]

print([url.replace(".com", "com").replace(".org", "org") for url in data])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`input = "cnnindonesia.com liputan.org"`

`output = input.replace(".", "")`

`print(output)`

### Output

cnnindonesiacom liputanorg

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple patterns, `re` would be useful:

```py
import re

s = "cnnindonesia.com liputan.org example.net twitch.tv"

output = re.sub(r"\.(com|org|net|tv)", r"\1", s)
print(output) # cnnindonesiacom liputanorg examplenet twitchtv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on the '.' and then join it.

```
input = "cnnindonesia.com liputan.org"

output = input.split(".")

output = ("").join(output)
```